# Write the result of the function evaluate in excel

Tags: excel, function, range, evaluate

i need to make a function : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JaRw.png

```
Function result(Ran As Range)

    Application.Volatile

    Dim columnNum  As Integer
    Dim rowNum  As Integer

    columnNum  = ActiveCell.Column
    rowNum  = ActiveCell.Row

    Ran.value = Evaluate(Cells(RowNum  , ColumnNum  - 1).Value)

End Function
```

it doesn't work

How can i write the result of the addition which is on the left?

Comment: Shouldn't the second result be 5? `1.5+1.5+2` = `3+2` = `5`.  And why are you having the function reference the cell the function resides in? Shouldn't it be `=Result(A1)` and `=Result(A2)` so that it looks at the data that's in A1 and A2?

Comment: Exactly, sorry, i can see the result with msgbox but i can't write it in B2 or B3

Comment: You can't update a cell using a function called as a UDF.  A function called in that way can only return a value (or array of values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems using a function named `result`. Changing the function name seemed to work.

See below:

```
Public Function doo(ran As Range)
    doo = Evaluate("=" & ran.Value)
End Function
```